# How to use join_axes in the column-wise axis concatenation using pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Data set:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2], 'B':[3, 4]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5, 6, 7], 'B':[8, 9, 10], 'C':[11, 12, 13]})
```

I am only able to use `join_axes` in the 'row-wise' concatenation when `axis=1` as shown below:

```
pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1, join_axes = [df2.index])
```

The above will yield:

[image]

However, trying this relative to `axis=0` will yield an error of `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'`:

```
pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=0, join_axes=[df2.index])
```

I have also tried making a list manually and that doesn't work either `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'equals'`:

```
pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=0, join_axes=['A'])
```

Expected output is (obtained from answer below):

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what the expected output should be?

Comment: @brimborium expected output is revised in main post. Already answered below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need set `join_axes` by columns of `df2`:

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df3], join_axes = [df2.columns])
print (df)
   A   B
0  1   3
1  2   4
0  5   8
1  6   9
2  7  10
```

Comment: Right it is not necessary in this case because an outer join would be sufficient. My example might not be the best, i'll revise it to show its benefit

Comment: @MarcSantos - OK, so removed second part of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe quicker:

```
df = df2.append(df3)
print(df)
   A   B
0  1   3
1  2   4
0  5   8
1  6   9
2  7  10
```

Comment: Thanks although I am mainly focused on trying to understand the `join_axes` argument of `pd.concat()`