# Pandas concat dataframes with different columns: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate two dataframes which have different column names along the 0 axis. I found a similar question here [How to use join_axes in the column-wise axis concatenation using pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494220/how-to-use-join-axes-in-the-column-wise-axis-concatenation-using-pandas-datafram) however this solution does not work for me since the column-names of my two dataframes are not the same. Since my original data is too large to post here the following example should illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1, 4)), columns=list('EFGH'))

#df1
    A   B   C   D
0   26  39  7   44

#df2
    E   F   G   H
0   12  44  26  64

pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
# desired output looks like this
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
0   26.0    39.0    7.0 44.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN 12.0    44.0    26.0    64.0
```

The above code works perfectly. However, once I input my own dataframes for df1 and df2, using the exact same syntax above, I get an error.

```
# my real dfs are called data1 & data2, I tried setting ignore_index=True and ignore_index=False
pd.concat([data1, data2],axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

results in the following error:

**Error:**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-194-dbee1fd0bdea> in <module>
    ----> 1 pd.concat([data1, data2],axis=0, ignore_index=True)

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
        224                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
        225                        copy=copy, sort=sort)
    --> 226     return op.get_result()
        227 
        228 

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in get_result(self)
        421             new_data = concatenate_block_managers(
        422                 mgrs_indexers, self.new_axes, concat_axis=self.axis,
    --> 423                 copy=self.copy)
        424             if not self.copy:
        425                 new_data._consolidate_inplace()

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in concatenate_block_managers(mgrs_indexers, axes, concat_axis, copy)
       5414                 values = values.view()
       5415             b = b.make_block_same_class(values, placement=placement)
    -> 5416         elif is_uniform_join_units(join_units):
       5417             b = join_units[0].block.concat_same_type(
       5418                 [ju.block for ju in join_units], placement=placement)

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in is_uniform_join_units(join_units)
       5438         # no blocks that would get missing values (can lead to type upcasts)
       5439         # unless we're an extension dtype.
    -> 5440         all(not ju.is_na or ju.block.is_extension for ju in join_units) and
       5441         # no blocks with indexers (as then the dimensions do not fit)
       5442         all(not ju.indexers for ju in join_units) and

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in <genexpr>(.0)
       5438         # no blocks that would get missing values (can lead to type upcasts)
       5439         # unless we're an extension dtype.
    -> 5440         all(not ju.is_na or ju.block.is_extension for ju in join_units) and
       5441         # no blocks with indexers (as then the dimensions do not fit)
       5442         all(not ju.indexers for ju in join_units) and

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'
```

I do not quite understand what this error message is trying to tell me. I've been trying to use fillna on both dataframes such that there should be no 'NoneType' anymore:

```
data2 = data2.fillna(999)
data1 = data1.fillna(999)
```

However, I still get the same error message.

The two dataframes I am using are quite large, so I cant unfortunately post the entire example here. The content of my two dataframes are just integers, floats and strings so nothing fancy going on here that would strike a possible cause of error. Any idea on what might cause this error or what I could check to narrow down the problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you explain what `is_extension` is? Is that a column name?

Comment: Hi @Efran, that's nothing I wrote. Judging from the error-message output, it appears to be inside pandas core ("~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py").

Comment: What's your pandas version? It works for me in pandas 0.22.0.

Comment: My version is '0.23.4'. Sorry if I caused some confusion: My small code example above works for me as well, however the problem is it breaks once I use my real data. Hence I guess it must be related to my data. I was hoping the error message would shed some light on what COULD be wrong with my data...but I cant interpret it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out the problem were just **duplicate column names** in one of my dataframes...Getting rid of those duplicates solved the problem. Above code now works flawless.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'` when I was appending two DataFrames. It was because I added `[]` twice by mistake when I changed one of the column name before appending them.

Example:

```
df.columns = [["A","B"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: The error described below has been fixed in [pandas 2.2.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52093), so if you observe the behaviour described below, the solution is to upgrade pandas.

Another potential problem that results in this type of error is when one of the columns contains all `None` values in one dataframe, but has tz-aware datetime values in another dataframe. Here's a small example to reproduce:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from pandas import DataFrame, concat

df1 = DataFrame({"c": [None, None]})
df2 = DataFrame({"c": [None, datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)]})
concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

The above raises `AttributeError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[173], line 7
      5 df1 = DataFrame({"c": [None, None]})
      6 df2 = DataFrame({"c": [None, datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)]})
----> 7 concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

File ~/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:393, in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    378     copy = False
    380 op = _Concatenator(
    381     objs,
    382     axis=axis,
   (...)
    390     sort=sort,
    391 )
--> 393 return op.get_result()

File ~/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:680, in _Concatenator.get_result(self)
    676             indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)
    678     mgrs_indexers.append((obj._mgr, indexers))
--> 680 new_data = concatenate_managers(
    681     mgrs_indexers, self.new_axes, concat_axis=self.bm_axis, copy=self.copy
    682 )
    683 if not self.copy and not using_copy_on_write():
    684     new_data._consolidate_inplace()
...
-> 2294         i8values = np.full(shape, fill_value._value)
   2295         return DatetimeArray(i8values, dtype=dtype)
   2297     elif is_1d_only_ea_dtype(dtype):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_value'
```

The solution is to explicitly assign dtype to the column containing all None values:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from pandas import DataFrame, concat

df1 = DataFrame({"c": [None, None]}).astype({"c": "datetime64[ns, UTC]"})
df2 = DataFrame({"c": [None, datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)]})
concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you - just hit the same thing, you've just saved me some painful debugging