# Error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'

Tags: python, pandas

I've the same issue : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension' as in this post : [Pandas concat dataframes with different columns: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_extension'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691385/pandas-concat-dataframes-with-different-columns-attributeerror-nonetype-obje). But I've tried what they say and it still doesn't work ...

Ì've two dataframe, df_score and importations :

```
Iso-2 FAOSTAT Production % Transformation %
CN      41      0.79388                1
```

and

```
Iso-2  FAOSTAT  Production %
US      231      0.079465
AU       10      0.063684
BR       21      0.027884
IN      100      0.025836
UZ      235      0.009251
```

I used `pd.concat` just like a few lines above in my code but this time this doesn't work, the line is `df_score = pd.concat([df_score, importations], axis = 0)`. I've tried to add `.reset_index(drop=True)` or set-up `ignore_index = True`directly in `pd.concat`. Does anyone have a clue about it ?

Comment: please post the actual code in question

Comment: Sorry my code is like this : ```df_score = pd.concat([df_score, importations], axis = 0)```